# Download many URLs in csv file and save as in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, csv, command-line

I have a csv file which has two columns: column A for image links and column B for names. First and second columns are comma separated.  I need to download all files in column A and assign them names in column B. I have tried the syntax below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=',' read -r url filename
do
wget -O $filename $url
done < urls.csv
```

However, I got these errors:

```
line 2: $'\r': command not found
line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
line 6: `done < urls.csv'
```

I am beginner with bash, any help with this?

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives, for example using awk, to process a file with field separator characters like a CSV.

However, I will try to KISS this specific case:

**Iterate through your CSV file** (while)

**Get each line fields** (IFS is used to set ',' as field separator)

**Use them with wget -O option** to specify a filename

e.g. something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=',' read -r url filename
do
    wget -O $filename $url
done < yourfile.csv
```

edit. Just copy pasted your snippet (which lacks proper identation inside the while loop..), and works properly

Perhaps you could share how are you executing that snippet ?

I'm saving it in 'test.sh' and launching it like this, having "urls.csv" file in same folder:

```
./test.sh
```